# I installed latte-dock and a lot of kde apps got installed

Tags: gnome, software-installation, kde

I installed latte dock using the command `sudo apt install latte-dock`. As soon as I installed it a lot of kde apps got installed. I logged out and there was a plasma wm also. So, I got the listed of dependecies of latte-dock using the command `apt show latte-dock` which showed this

```
Package: latte-dock
Version: 0.9.11-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 4,925 kB
Depends: plasma-desktop, kpackagetool5, libc6 (>= 2.29), libkf5activities5 (>= 5.23.0), libkf5archive5 (>= 5.2.0+git20141006), libkf5configcore5 (>= 5.24.0), libkf5configgui5 (>= 4.97.0), libkf5coreaddons5 (>= 5.62.0), libkf5crash5 (>= 4.96.0), libkf5dbusaddons5 (>= 4.97.0), libkf5declarative5 (>= 5.45.0), libkf5globalaccel5 (>= 5.0.0), libkf5guiaddons5 (>= 4.96.0), libkf5i18n5 (>= 4.97.0), libkf5iconthemes5 (>= 4.96.0), libkf5newstuff5 (>= 5.27.0), libkf5notifications5 (>= 4.96.0), libkf5package5 (>= 5.17.0), libkf5plasma5 (>= 5.41.0), libkf5plasmaquick5 (>= 5.28.0), libkf5quickaddons5 (>= 5.26.0), libkf5service-bin, libkf5service5 (>= 4.96.0), libkf5waylandclient5 (>= 4:5.52.0), libkf5windowsystem5 (>= 5.30.0), libkf5xmlgui-bin, libkf5xmlgui5 (>= 4.96.0), libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.9.0~), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta3) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.9.0~beta3), libqt5qml5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0) | libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.9.0~), libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.9.0~), libstdc++6 (>= 5), libx11-6, libxcb-randr0, libxcb1
Homepage: https://userbase.kde.org/LatteDock
Download-Size: 963 kB
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Dock based on plasma frameworks
 Latte is a dock based on plasma frameworks that provides an elegant and
 intuitive experience for your tasks and plasmoids. It animates it's
 contents by using parabolic zoom effect and tries to be there only when
 it is needed.
```

I uninstalled the first two packages using commands, `sudo apt purge latte-dock plasma-desktop kpackagetool5`, and restarted gnome to find most of things such as (icon theme, cursor theme, plasma, etc) were uninstalled but still the terminal theme and font remained,I changed those manually and now only this app remains.

[image]

Can anybody suggest me how to remove this?

Comment: latte dock is quite tied in with KDE. It is probably not wise to consider it if you object against all the dependencies it needs. a safer way to use it and remove some clutter is to install it, and then hide the application ions of applications that were installed with it but which you do not want to use.

Comment: It wasn't just the application, they changed fonts, system theme, cursor theme, icon theme and everything.